# Recording landline phone calls

Tags: electronics, peripherals, software-development

My cell phone is recording all phone calls  (using Automatical Call Recorder on Android) and this has helped me a lot of times (both because I didn't hear something very clearly or as evidence for something).

Now I want to do the same for my landline phone (RJ11 connection, Belgian phone line). I have a Raspberry Pi 3 Mode B I received as a gift and haven't used yet. I was wondering if I could use my Raspberry Pi for this? In the ideal scenario it's recording all calls and storing them on my NAS.

I'm a programmer so if necessary I can code. I have little to none experience with building electronics.

Is this doable? If yes, where/how do I start?

Comment: Be very careful doing this. It's illegal, in some parts of the world, to record a phone conversation without informing the other party at the start of the call. You'll also need to edit your question (*don't use comments*) to provide the country you're working in - phone connectors can vary between regions.

Comment: @goobering It's their own landline. I think it's cool. I also use the same app on my phone.

Comment: @PandaLion98 I enjoy a fine doodad as much as the next person. Sucks a little if you rely on the recording for something important and it lands you in court. Exercise a little caution is all - make sure you understand the rules for where you're recording.

Comment: Just did some research on the laws regarding this in my country and as long as I'm one of the two parties in the call (so I'm not for example recording the calls my neighbor is making) there's no problem and the recordings can even be used in court as evidence (up to the judge if he uses it or not). So legally it's no problem. But after some Googling it sounds like this will technically be very hard.

Comment: @Lander Where you at?

Comment: @pandalion98 that's a foolish and naive point of view. Depending on the jurisdiction, this could fall under wiretapping laws. Many US states require both parties to consent to any kind of audio recording.

Comment: @jacobm001 hence why I asked where OP is located. For example, in Italy, recording and using (in court) recorded phone calls does not require permission whatsoever, provided the recording party is a participant.

Comment: I'm in Belgium. Here it's no problem as long as one of the parties (me) agrees.

Comment: @goobering In general, you can record conversations freely for personal use, at least in EU. You need to inform the other party about the recording if you plan to use the recording as evidence later. At any rate, the question is addressing technical aspects, not legal ones.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev The law is *very different* in the US and, presumably, many other parts of the world, and this is a global site. Where possible I will attempt to keep anyone asking questions in good faith out of prison so that they can continue to provide me with imaginary internet points.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My approach to this would be to do everything I possibly could to avoid interfacing the Pi directly with the phone line. It's definitely achievable, but it sounds a lot harder than I like my spare time.

Some Googling suggests that it shouldn't be too difficult or expensive to get hold of something that looks like [this £16 adapter from Maplin](http://www.maplin.co.uk/p/play-and-record-telephone-recording-adapter-zq81c?cmpid=ppc&gclid=CM3l9bXV6NECFUcQ0wodqGUFLw). It accepts (I'm pretty sure) an RJ11 in from the phone socket, and outputs audio to a 3.5mm jack. That particular device, I note, is extremely badly reviewed - I suspect there may be better alternatives on Ebay.

Now you have to get the audio into the Pi. I'd recommend a [USB soundcard](https://www.adafruit.com/product/1475).

Now all we have to do is listen to the audio input and trigger a recording if the incoming amplitude peaks over a threshold. There's currently a really good writeup on using [SoX](http://sox.sourceforge.net/) to do exactly this at [pibat.afraidofsunlight.co.uk](http://pibat.afraidofsunlight.co.uk/sound-activated-recording):

> By specifying the right parameters to SoX’s silence command, sound can
>   be monitored effectively trimming all noise until noise is detected,
>   and then trim everything after so many seconds of silence.
>
> This can be achieved with the following command:
>
> ```
> rec - c1 -r 192000 record.wav silence 1 0.1 1% 1 5.0 1% : newfile : restart
> ```

Comment: I've bought this one: http://www.dx.com/en/p/rj11-telephone-line-pass-thru-to-3-5mm-mini-jack-conversation-recording-line-out-adapter-18869

If it doesn't work, I haven't lost much money.

Comment: @Coder14 Did it work ?

Comment: @Salah, sorry, moved on to other projects. Don',t really use my landline a lot anymore and I'm thinking to just cancel the service. So I can't tell you more if it works or not.